# GemFile is missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm trying to configure Project Sprout for as3 on my Ubuntu 14.10, but i'm getting an error when i'm trying to configure the project(sprout-as3 SomeProject), on the official website of ProjectSprout is said that i need to execute this command: bundle install, and now i got this error:

Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

searching on the web i found that the rubygems file isn't on the project directory, but i dont know where it is, i'm new on ruby and bundle, if someone could help me i'll be thankfull?

Answer (score 0):

Create New `Gemfile` in your project, with default gems -

```
 source "https://rubygems.org"


 # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
 gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
 # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
 gem 'sqlite3'
 # Use SCSS for stylesheets
 gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
 # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 # Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
 # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
 # gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

 # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
 gem 'jquery-rails'
 # Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
 gem 'turbolinks'
 # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
 gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
 # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
 gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

 # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
 gem 'spring',        group: :development


 ...........
```

and try `bundle install`

Comment: created the gemfile and put this content inside but it wont work

Comment: The same error, i was reading the sprout error description to build a new project and it cant find the iconv that is rquired, so i tried gem install iconv and, for changing, got a new error:  [code]ERROR:  Error installing iconv:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1[/code]

Answer (score 0):

OOOOk, now it is apparently working, a installed the ruby devlopment with sudo apt-get install ruby-dev, and then installed the iconv gem, use the sprout-as3 my_project to generate my project, cd to the project dir and run bundle install, it works!, thanks for attention Amit ;)